# How can I deal with the race condition in the code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, race-condition

In the class below the function result() will display the value of the variable 
`whatToDo` accordingly the functions `addition` and `multiplication` are called.

**Condition**: Here, in the below code what if `whatTodo` is `addition` but function `addition` is only not called.

**Question**: How can I deal this **Condition**?

```
class SomeClass{

let whatToDo: string;

public result(){
        if ( this.whatToDo == 'additon'){
             return this.whatToDo;
           }
        else if (this.whatToDo == 'multiplcation'){
              return this.whatToDo;
}

}
public addition(){
    this.whatToDo = 'addition';
     //do something
}

public multiplication(){
  this.whatToDo = 'multiplication';
     //do something
}
}
```

Use case - When `whatTodo` is assigned as `addition` before calling addition(), so it should tell that `whatToDo` is `undefined` so that it can be easily differentiated that addition() is not yet called.This what I want ot achieve.

Comment: `the function result() will display` nothing actually

Comment: Please explain your question better, for me this question makes no sense at all.

Comment: Please can you share an example of calling your code, and the expected output from calling it?

Comment: i don't see a race condition in the code. (a race condition is when you have two or more threads that modify the same resource)

Comment: _When `whatTodo` is assigned as `"addition"` before calling `addition()`_ Well, when is that going to happen?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just a typo, try:

```
public result(){
        if ( this.whatToDo == 'addition'){
             return this.whatToDo;
           }
        else if (this.whatToDo == 'multiplication'){
              return this.whatToDo;
}
```

You misspelled the words "additon" and "multiplcation" in your code.

Comment: please ignore typos

Comment: Are you sure, because the way the code is now it won't return anything. Try adding an else after the else if with return nothing